# Enable logging for single build plugin in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I need to see the full logs from dependency-check plugin in Maven (I am looking at running it offline) which `-X` enables.

Unfortunately this generates so much output that the information I'm looking for cannot be kept in the IntelliJ console buffer.

Is there a way to tell Maven to do something similar to enableing -X just for a single plugin?